# Validating a password using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a password validation in JS to accept 8-15 digits with at least 1 lower case with this function below, however, it always returns True!

```
function validatepassword(){
  var pass= document.getElementById("pass1").value;
  var tester= /^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])[\w]]{8,15}$/;
  if (tester.test(pass))
  {
      document.getElementById("p1prompt").innerHTML=("valid " + "&#10004");
      document.getElementById("p1prompt").style.color="green";
      return true;
  }
  else {
      document.getElementById("p1prompt").style.color="red";
      document.getElementById("p1prompt").innerHTML=("at least 8 digits containing a lower case");
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `[\w]]` is your problem. There's an extra right square bracket.

Comment: I should add that this sort of restriction on password contents (particularly a low upper-bound on length) is bad for security.

Comment: Yeah, you don't want to be limiting to 15 characters. There's no good reason to do so.

Comment: Why do people insist on attempting to use one regex to do all the things? Regex is great if you need to match a simple pattern, but otherwise, use other tools, or more than one regex.

Comment: The best thing you can do is limit the minimum length and that should be the only restriction. This as it allows users to choose passwords they feel they can memorize which decreases the chance they will write them down which is a sure way that it could easily be stolen. A maximum password length never makes sense unless the system is storing them in plain text in which case you need to address that before you do anything else.

Comment: `pass.length > 7 && /\d/.test(pass) && /[a-z]/.test(pass)` is that so hard?

Comment: @zzzzBov but why do it that way when you can write a single difficult-to-understand regex?

Comment: You should return true at the *end* of your function, not at the start (return early on false-checking if statements). This means you don't need a bunch of if/else arrow code. Also, if you're providing feedback on a form, you might need to replicate that behaviour on another form, so you should avoid IDs in your JS altogether and use data attributes. You can see both of these ideas in action here (albeit with jQuery instead of vanilla JS): https://jsfiddle.net/7otzcojo/

Comment: Also, I hope you're aware 8+ digits is very difficult for the average user to remember unless they use a very obvious number like their telephone number, which is terribly insecure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**
Special thanks to [Smarx](/users/94559/smarx) for allowing to use his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44596830/4758494).

```js
function validatepassword(){
var pass= document.getElementById("pass1").value;
if (/[a-z]/.test(pass) && /\d/.test(pass) && pass.length >= 8 && pass.length <= 15)
{
    document.getElementById("p1prompt").innerHTML=("valid " + "&#10004");
    document.getElementById("p1prompt").style.color="green";
    return true;
}
else {
    document.getElementById("p1prompt").style.color="red";
    document.getElementById("p1prompt").innerHTML=("at least 8 characters containing a lower case");
    return false;
}
}
```

```html
Password : <input type="password" id="pass1">
<p id="p1prompt"></p>
<button onclick='validatepassword()' type="button">Validate</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, the validation works, but still when I try to test 
    if(validatepassword){
    console.log("True");
    }
    else{
    console.log("False");
    }

it always gives true

Comment: Change `if(validatepassword)` to `if(validatepassword())`

Comment: This regular expression matches 8-15 digits followed by at least one lowercase letter. It's quite unclear what the original question is asking for, but I doubt it's this.

Comment: My previous comment is no longer valid. This now appears to be identical to my answer (but I'm still not sure that's what the original question is asking for).

Comment: @smarx Thank you for pointing out the error after carefully reading the question even I reached the same conclusion. My first answer was incorrect. Apologies. Took inspiration from your answer and updated the code. I hope it's okay or I can delete it.

Comment: But it says "digits?"

Comment: Sometimes 'digits' means alphanumeric characters. OP has to clarify on this and update his question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I misread the question... I'm actually no longer sure what it's asking for. (The regular expression and the description and the error message in the code all suggest different password requirements.)

The answer below tests for "8-15 characters including at least one digit and at least one lowercase letter."

---

Although my comment above gives a fix to the regular expression, when you find yourself using a somewhat complicated expression, sometimes it's better to simplify your code by using multiple simpler tests instead. For example:

```
function isValid(password) {
    return /[a-z]/.test(password) && // contains a lowercase letter
           /\d/.test(password) &&    // contains a digit
           password.length >= 8 &&   // at least 8 characters
           password.length <= 15;    // no more than 15 characters
}
```

But again, these restrictions are harmful for your users' security. It prevents them from using good, long, random passwords.